# Why is the "parse" method not called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Callback doesn't call **parse** method when `url` with additional path `https://www.businessesforsale.com/search`, but it work with url `https://www.businessesforsale.com`

```
import scrapy
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['businessesforsale.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.businessesforsale.com/search', self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        print('Some actions...')
```

Comment: ave you tried without overiding def start_requests(self): but just specifying start_urls

Comment: Works fine for me when using `scrapy runspider`. How are you executing the code? Also, showing your log output is always a good idea.

Comment: but when i try to use `scrapy crawl test` it doesn't work